# Как на страницу с товаром в k2store вместо фотографии товара Item image preview вывести Media preview

Tags: joomla

Добрый день имеется сайт интернет магазин в котором код

```
<span class="itemImage">
        <a class="modal" rel="{handler: 'image'}" href="<?php echo $this-
>item->imageXLarge; ?>" 
title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_CLICK_TO_PREVIEW_IMAGE'); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $this->item->image; ?>
" alt="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo 
K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item-
>image_caption);
else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>" 
style="width:<?php echo $this->item->imageWidth; ?>
px;height:auto;" />
        </a>
      </span>
```

выводит Item image preview
как вывести вместо Item image preview 
Media preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($this->item->videoType=='embedded'): ?>
    <div class="videoWrapper">
        <?php echo $this->item->video; ?>
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <span class="itemVideo"><?php echo $this->item->video; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Все ок